Create a trendline variable
i'm looking for create a variable with the linear fit data, so i can add to the map layer the new raster map with this band (variable), do you know how to do this?

i want to create a raster where each pixel contain his unique trendline value (in this case, 0.674).
i hope it colud be possible,

You can reduce an ImageCollection so that each pixel has its own linear regression coefficients using reduce(ee.Reduce.linearRegression).
